# Why is “or” (in logic) sometimes equivalent to “and” (in natural language)?

Tags: logic, soft-question, propositional-calculus

In classical propositional logic, **or** (aka. *disjunction*) is a Boolean function $\vee:\{0,1\}^2\longrightarrow\{0,1\}$ defined as $\vee:=\{ (00,0), (01,1), (10,1),(11,1) \}$, and **and** (aka. *conjunction*) is a Boolean function $\wedge: \{0,1\}^2\longrightarrow\{0,1\}$ defined as $\{(00,0),(01,0),(10,0),(11,1)\}$.

There's also [rules of inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_inference) for these functions, such as $\vee$-introduction, $\wedge$-introduction, $\vee$-elimination, and $\wedge$-elimination, as well as other machinery from logic.

---

So, **or** and **and** are not the same object. But when using them in math reasoning, sometimes the 2 can be used interchangeably.

**Example.** Let $X$ be a topological space, let $A\subseteq X$, let $\text{Lim }A$ be the set of [limit points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) of $A$. The *closure* of $A$ is defined as $A\cup\text{Lim }A$. But the set $A\cup \text{Lim }A$ is defined as the set $\{x\in X\ |\ x\in A\ \vee\ x\in \text{Lim }A\}$, namely, the set of all $x\in X$ where $x\in A$ **or** $x\in \text{Lim }A$. Equivalently, th closure of $A$ is the set $A$ *and* its limit points.

(This is the first example that came to mind, but hopefully you get the idea.)

I know I'm mixing formal logic with natural (human!) language to the point of frivolity, but I'm wondering if there's a non-mundane reason for this equivalence. Perhaps **or** and **and** are "dual", in some sense? Or perhaps the equivalence arises just because natural language is really weird?

(One could disregard this question by saying "the meaning of **or** in logic is not the same as in natural language" (usually natural language uses *exclusive-or*), just like the meaning of **if** in logic is not the same as in natural language (usually natural language uses *if-and-only-if*), but I get the feeling something else is going on.)

Comment: There is duality via deMorgan. Also, e.g.,  $(p\land q)\to r$ is equivalent to $(p\to r)\lor (q\to r)$

Comment: That is because the logical 'AND' corresponds to the INTERSECTION in set theory, which in turn corresponds to the 'AND' in the English language. Likewise for the logical 'OR', which corresponds to the UNION in set theory, which corresponds to the 'OR' in the English language.

Comment: The word *and* is often used for adding: "3 and 5 is 8", "this things and those things". In mathematics these, especially the last expression, correspond to taking a union, which in logics correspond to *or*.

Comment: I think that at least to some extent this question is comparing apples and oranges. (Try to rewrite _that_ in predicate logic!)

Comment: This is more of an English language question than a math question. Why does the English word "and" sometimes correspond to the logical "or" connective?

Comment: To be honest I find that the English in that example is simply wrong. Can you find another one?

Comment: @TannerSwett I agree! And this is the kind of math question we should answer if we're to teach computers how to understand natural language =)

Comment: The set of *A* and *B* is a set of their union. Union arises from disjunction.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Consider: "All fruits and vegetables are nutritious"

Rather than:

$$\forall x ((F(x) \land V(x)) \rightarrow N(x)) \text{ Wrong!}$$

it translates as:

$$\forall x ((F(x) \lor V(x)) \rightarrow N(x))$$

But it *also* translates as (and is indeed equivalent to):

$$\forall x (F(x)\rightarrow N(x))\land \forall x (V(x) \rightarrow N(x))$$

So now we see that "Fruits and vegetables are nutritious" is really just shorthand for "fruits are nutritious and vegetables are nutritious"

Applied to your case:

"the closure of A is the set A and its limit points."

can be translated as:

$$\forall x ((x \in A \lor x \in \text{Lim} A) \rightarrow x \in Closure(A))$$

or as:

$$\forall x (x \in A \rightarrow x \in Closure(A)) \land \forall x (x \in \text{Lim} A) \rightarrow x \in Closure(A))$$

In other words, the confusion is because of the difference between the *disjunction of conditions* and *conjunction of conditionals*.

Comment: I think you should add a paragraph on how this breaks apart when analysing a linguistic “*or*” and another one on how and why the latter translations really reflect the linguistic usage of “*and*” instead of the wrong one.

Comment: So I think the answer concerns: $1)$ the way __then__ right-distributes over __or__ (in propositional and predicate logic), so that $(A\vee B) \Longrightarrow C$ equals $(A\Longrightarrow C)\wedge (B\Longrightarrow C)$, and $2)$ how (the universal closures of) these 2 statements translate to natural language ("all A and B are C")

Comment: @étale-cohomology Exactly!  Glad I could help :)

Comment: By they way, the point raised here can be expressed in terms of my answer: “Rather than $F ∩ V ⊆ N$ the sentence *All fruits and vegetables are nutritious* translates to $F ⊆ N$ *and* $V ⊆ N$, that is to say $F ∪ V ⊆ N$”. (Yeah, I’m advertising my own answer here – sue me. I put a lot of effort into it and I think I’ve done a good job in the end. Hope you don’t mind, Bram.)

Comment: @k.stm Don't worry, I won't sue you! In fact, i'll give you an upvote; good answer!

Answer (score 11):

This is a vague question, of course, but I want to try to give some
perspective on it based on some thinking I’ve done lately.

I think this is a matter of implicitly using active / passive, which behave dually in a somewhat precise mathematical manner. First, closely observe how
we use active and passive regarding the relation of containment:

Let $X$ be a given set, and let $A$, $B$ and $T$ be subsets of $X$.  Then we say

- $T$ contains $A$ *and* $B$, when we mean $T \supseteq A ∪ B$, and
- $T$ is contained by $A$ *and* $B$, when we mean $T ⊆ A ∩ B$.

This is because we actually mean to avoid repeating some clauses
by using the conjunction “and”, in order to shorten
sentences. The statements above are (most often) linguistically perceived
to be equivalent to respectively

- $T$ contains $A$ *and* $T$ contains $B$.
- $T$ is contained by $A$ *and* $T$ is contained by $B$.

So, the conjunction “*and*” implicitly serves as a conjunction of sentences or propositions.

Note: I don’t mean to define mathematical parlance here, I try to
observe it.

Now, if we say that “*the closure of $A$ is $A$ and its limits points*”,
I suspect we immediately understand this to say “*the closure of
$A$ is the set $T$ containing (exactly) $A$ and all limit points of $A$*”. By the above observation, that is the set $T$ such that $T \supseteq A ∪ B$ (when $B$ denotes the limit points of $A$) and $T$ contains nothing more (so $T = A ∪ B$).

However, if we use “*and*” in other contexts as “*$T$ is in $A$ and $B$*”, we mean “$T$ is contained in $A$ and $B$”, so $T ⊆ A ∩ B$.

---

Mathematically, this can be interpreted e.g. [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order))-theoretically: Let $L = (L, ≤, ∨, ∧)$ be a lattice, $∨$ denoting the join (maximum) of two elements, $∧$ denoting the meet (minimum) of two elements. Then there’s a dual lattice $L^{\mathrm{op}} = (L, ≥, ∧, ∨)$ and $L$ and $L^{\mathrm{op}}$ are antitonely isomorphic as lattices.

In the dual lattice $L^\mathrm{op}$, let’s write for all $x, y ∈ L$

- “$y ≤'x$” if $y ≥ x$ in $L$,
- “$x ∨' y$” for $x ∧ y$ in $L$,
- “$x ∧' y$” for $x ∨ y$ in $L$.

So $L^\mathrm{op}$ has order $≤'$, join $∨'$ and meet $∧'$.

If we introduce parlance for the relation, the antitone isomorphism is reflected in our language. For elements $x, y ∈ L$, let’s say $x$ *kills* $y$ whenever $x ≤ y$ in $L$. (I like *killing* here because it's so violently vivid.) As humans, we now also *automatically* say $y$ *is killed by* $x$ for $x ≤ y$, that is for $y ≤' x$.

Next, observe that for $a, b, t ∈ L$
$$t ≤ a ∧ b \Longleftrightarrow t ≤ a~\text{and}~t ≤ b.$$
Using our parlance:
$$\text{$t$ kills $a ∧ b$} \Longleftrightarrow \text{$t$ kills $a$ and $b$}$$
This justifies $a ∧ b$ to be called “*$a$ and $b$*”.

And the analogous is true for $L^{\mathrm{op}}$ (where we have to add primes “$'$” to all symbols and replace “*kills*” by “*is killed by*”). Therefore, for $a, b, t ∈ L$, we have
\begin{align*}
\text{$t$ is killed by $a$ and $b$} &⇔ t ≤' a ∧' b' \\
&⇔t ≥ a ∨ b \\
&⇔\text{$t$ is killed by $a ∨ b$},
\end{align*}
also justiying $a ∨ b$ to be called “*$a$ and $b$*”.

The difference lies in which perspective we take on an implicit relation – from above or from below. And it depends on whether we use (implicit) verbs describing the relation in active or passive.

In our case, $L$ is the powerset of some space $X$ with $\supseteq$ as order and *killing* is *containing*.

This also explains why such a confusion doesn't happen when lingustically using “*or*”: We never say “*$A$ or $B$*” as in “*the closure of $A$ is $A$ or its limit points*”. This is because $t ≤ a ∨ b ⇔ \text{$t ≤ a$ or $t ≤ b$}$ does not hold for general lattices (think of disjoint union), so there’s no justification for saying “*$a$ or $b$*” for $a ∨ b$; and there need not be any other element fulfilling this universal property: There is (in general) no set “containing exactly $A$ or its limit points”.

(And in a sense, this generalises to categories with limits and colimits.)

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how you word it.  Does $A \cup B$ correspond to "or" (as the notation $\vee$ for "or" suggests), or does it correspond so "and"?

You argue that $A \cup B$ corresponds to "and", since
$$
A \cup B\quad\text{consists of both}\quad A\quad\text{and}\quad B
$$

The reasoning I guess used by Boole and his followers is: $A \cup B$ corresponds to "or" since
$$
A \cup B = \{x\;:\; x \in A \text{ or } x \in B\}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Common language "do A or B" is interpreted corresponding to formal language "do either A or B". This is symptomatic when scientific patterns are applied to real life phenomena. As you wrote, mixing common and formal language can be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can write $(x \in A) \lor (x \in B) \implies (x \in C)$
or equivalently you can write
$(A \subseteq C) \land (B \subseteq C).$

Answer (score 2):

The same question comes up in computer programming, where new programmers often write incorrect code that *sounds* correct if you read it aloud and interpret it as an English sentence. The most common mistake is thinking "if x equals 1 or 2, ...", and writing

```
if x = 1 OR 2
```

when what they really need to write is

```
if x = 1 OR x = 2
```

Different languages have different syntactical variations, but there is a common theme: in the English sentence, the word "or" joins 2 nouns, and the disjunction becomes the object of the verb "equals". The "equals" operator in English can take a numeric object $x$ on one side, and a disjunction of a set of numeric objects $\vee S$ on the other side. It produces a result defined by:

$$\mathrm{equals}(x, \vee S) \longleftrightarrow \bigvee_{i\,\in\,S} \mathrm{equals}(x,i)$$

The OR operators in math and most computer languages don't do anything like that. What does $\vee S$ even mean if $S=\{1,2\}$? What's $1\vee2$? It's a grammatical object that native English speakers can process without any effort, and it *sounds* like it's made of good, logical, mathematical words, so it's surprising to many people the first time they see a computer fail to interpret it the "obvious" way.

To write the statement correctly using math-style $\vee$ or computer-style OR, you must be able to form an equivalent statement in a restricted English in which "or" can only be used to join an independent clause making a statement of fact with another independent clause making a statement of fact. When you have "and" or "or" joining nouns in your English sentence, you'll be in trouble if you try to blindly translate it word by word into an equation.

In your example "and" is joining "the set $A$" and "its limit points", both of which are noun phrases. That's how you know that's a non-math-y "and".

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be explained in another way which might be a bit easier for one to understand.

Now let's assume we have two independent simple statements:

s1 (e.g. 1+1=2)
s2 (e.g. 1+1>2)

And with them, we can generate two compound Statements:

S1: s1 and s2 (e.g. 1+1=2 and 1+1>2)
S2: s1 or s2  (e.g. 1+1=2 or 1+1>2)

If S1 is true, both s1 and s2 must be true at the same time, since for the example I gave above, S1 is false. (1+1=2 is true but 1+1>2 is false)

If S2 is true, it means at least one of s1 and s2 is true, which means as long as one of them is true, then "s1 or s2" is true. So for the example above, S2 is true. (1+1=2 is true so regardless of s2’s truthfulness, the Statement “1+1=2 or 1+1>2” is true.) In other words, s1 and s2 must both be false at the same time to output a “false” value of "s1 or s2”.

To put it into more formal and academical words in logics, “And” is referred as “Logical Conjunction” and “Or” as “Logical Disjunction”
and part of the Binary Operations, a type of Truth Table.[1]

Hope this helps.

[1]. *Anellis, Irving H.*, [**Peirce’s truth-functional analysis and the origin of the truth table**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/01445340.2011.621702), Hist. Philos. Log. 33, No. 1, 87-97 (2012). [ZBL1270.03008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1270.03008).

Answer (score 1):

In the example, even though the closure of $A$ contains both $A$ and its limit points as sets, a point of the closure does not have to be in both. I think this is the root of confusion in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

In English, "AND" has the same meaning as AND. "OR" usually has the same meaning as XOR. If English-speakers wish to emulate the value of the logical OR, they use "AND/OR". The EITHER-OR and NEITHER-NOR constructions in English are obviously XOR constructions. (NEITHER-NOR is equivalent to EITHER X OR Y = NOT-Z.)

As to *why* this is true, I have no idea.

Comment: Not true. 'Either .. or ...' in English is not necessarily the exclusive or. I can say 'I want to be either rich or happy', and everyone understand that I am just fine with being both rich and happy. ANd the  'neither ...nor' *always* means neither one, i.e. the negation of the inclusive or: 'I am neither rich nor happy' means 'I am not rich and i am not happy', so that has nothing to do with the XOR.

Answer (score 1):

The sense of connectives flips across the boundary between foreground and background (much like the sense of an inequality flips when you multiply it through by -1). For example, if you’re the IT person in your company and the boss says to you, “Give me a list of all our salesreps living in Chicago and Boston.”, then you know that as you pass the salesrep file, you change the boss’s “and” to logical “or”. That is, you output the salesrep’s information if, and only if, the salesrep lives in Chicago OR the salesrep lives in Boston. (The boss was being “illogical”, because the boss is always in foreground, and foreground, the terrain of ‘natural language’, is governed not by logic, but by perception and convenience.) So, a foreground ‘and’ becomes a background ‘or’. Also, a foreground ‘or’ becomes a background ‘and’. For example, if you are the hospitality agent for your company and the boss says to you, “We want to offer each guest the choice of coffee or tea.”, then in background (that is, in the company kitchen) you have to prepare a batch of coffee AND a batch of tea. So, a foreground ‘or’ becomes a background ‘and’. Also, problematical situations are alluded to or acknowledged by using this flip-phenomenon. Specifically, the natural habitat of tautologies is, of course, background. Therefore, foregrounding a tautology (by, for example, saying it in the presence of others) alludes to or acknowledges a problem. For example, it is tautologically true that boys will be boys, but if you happen to overhear someone actually SAYING so, you can be pretty sure it’s not good news that they are commenting on. To take another example, someone wearing a shirt that says, “It is what it is.” is endemically unhappy about something in the world.

(This is a re-post of what I have written [here.](http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/temo-conjunction.html))